# Bulk inserts into table

Tags: database, postgresql, rust, bulkinsert, rust-sqlx

Let's say i have one struct

```
pub struct Student {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}
```

I have list of Student type & i want to insert it into postgres table
in single query.

I am following [this](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/main/FAQ.md#how-can-i-bind-an-array-to-a-values-clause-how-can-i-do-bulk-inserts) (`UNNEST()`) it has egs for primitive type list but not for structs.

My code snippet

```
sqlx::query!(
    "INSERT INTO students(name, age) SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1::text[], $2::int8[])",
    &students[..]
)
    .execute(&pool)
    .await.unwrap();
```

What should i change in above code snippet to insert multiple rows at once?

Answer (score 1):

Like in the article you linked you have to pass multiple slices of primitives instead of one slice of complex objects:

```rust
let (names, ages): (Vec<&String>, Vec<&i32>) =
    students.iter().map(|Student { name, age }| (name, age));
sqlx::query!(
    "INSERT INTO students(name, age) SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1::text[], $2::int8[])",
    &names[..],
    &ages[..]
)
.execute(&pool)
.await
.unwrap();
```